# boolean logic Are both boolean logic equal

Tags: boolean-logic

```
A && B || C && D

(A && B) || (C && D)
```

Are both boolean logic equal in C++? I am confused.

Comment: Please search first. The keywords here are immediately `c++` and `boolean operator`. Another useful word is `precedence`. There should be no shortage of useful information online. (Random first hit: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not they're equal depends entirely on how you define your operator precedence.  If `&&` takes precedence over `||`, then yes.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: @retide Search for `c++ operator precedence`. Question diverted!

Comment: @pst has the *right* answer, but I'm sure there will be other answers here shortly that fill in the C++-specific information for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the most programming languages you'll find that operator `&&` is of higher priority than `||`.
So for example in Java, C#, C, C++, Python, Ruby, etc.

```
A && B || C && D
```

is equivalent to

```
(A && B) || (C && D)
```

You can even copy-paste the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        bool A = false;
        bool B = false;
        bool C = true;
        bool D = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            A = (i == 0);
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
               B = (j == 0);
                for(int k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
                   C = (k == 0);
                    for(int l = 0; l < 2; ++l) {
                       D = (l == 0);
                       cout << A << " " << B << " " << C << " " << D << " -> ";
                       cout << ((A && B || C && D) == ((A && B) || (C && D)))  << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

to [Ideone](http://ideone.com) to find out for yourself. In C++ for example the output is:

```
1 1 1 1 -> 1
1 1 1 0 -> 1
1 1 0 1 -> 1
1 1 0 0 -> 1
1 0 1 1 -> 1
1 0 1 0 -> 1
1 0 0 1 -> 1
1 0 0 0 -> 1
0 1 1 1 -> 1
0 1 1 0 -> 1
0 1 0 1 -> 1
0 1 0 0 -> 1
0 0 1 1 -> 1
0 0 1 0 -> 1
0 0 0 1 -> 1
0 0 0 0 -> 1
```

So the `((A && B || C && D) == ((A && B) || (C && D)))` is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

While the final answer goes to the specifics of the C++ language you're asking about, here's some food for thought on why (and possibly how) to remember:

Conjunction (AND, &&) is often associated with multiplication, while disjunction (OR, ||) is often associated with addition (and we generally know the precedence of multiplication over addition).

Here's a quote from http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~fricke/projects/quinto/dnf.html:

> ... As a practical matter, we usually associate conjunction with
>   multiplication and disjunction with addition. Indeed, if we identify
>   true with 1 and false with 0, then {0,1} coupled with the usual
>   definitions of addition and multiplication over the Galois field of
>   size 2 (eg, arithmetic modulo 2), then addition (+) and disjunction
>   (or) really are the same, as are multiplication and conjunction (and).
>   ...

Speaking in rather general terms, the computer languages tend to honor the precedence of multiplicative operators over additive operators.

*(Further, these associations, e.g. between operators in logic and in algebra reoccur in other areas, such as type systems.  For an interesting exposition of that, see http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011 on the notion of Algebraic Type Systems.)*